# Premission denied when doing "sudo ./ "command

Tags: permissions

First of all, I've tried googling this to no avail, and I apologize if the answer is already out there (new to Ubuntu 16.04), but i cannot for the life of me figure out whats wrong here.

I've downloaded MATLAB from my university and I'm trying to run the install file with

```
    sudo ./install
```

which returns

```
    ./install: 1: exec: /home/oystein/matlab_r2017a_linux/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

I've already tried the following

```
    chmod +x install
    chmod a+x install
    chmod u+x install
```

in order to change the premissions. The MATLAB folder is located in /home/oystein/. Output from

```
    ls -al
```

is

```
    total 4384
    drwxrwxr-x  9 oystein oystein    4096 okt.  17 13:57 .
    drwxrwxr-x 22 oystein oystein    4096 okt.  17 13:57 ..
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein    3371 mars  21  2011 activate.ini
    drwxrwxr-x  7 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 archives
    drwxrwxr-x  3 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 bin
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein       0 feb.  24  2017 .dvd1
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein       0 feb.  24  2017 .dvd2
    drwxrwxr-x  3 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 etc
    drwxrwxr-x  5 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 help
    -rwxrwxr-x  1 oystein oystein    8179 jan.  19  2017 install
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein    9922 feb.  17  2017 installer_input.txt
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein 4319706 feb.  14  2017 install_guide.pdf
    drwxrwxr-x  5 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 java
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein   73669 feb.  24  2017 license_agreement.txt
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein   13162 jan.  12  2017 patents.txt
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein    6282 feb.  17  2017 readme.txt
    drwxrwxr-x  3 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 sys
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein     245 des.  28  2013 trademarks.txt
    drwxrwxr-x  3 oystein oystein    4096 feb.  24  2017 ui
    -rw-rw-r--  1 oystein oystein      36 mars  28  2017 version.txt
```

The premissions tab of the home folder shows ***Create and delete files*** for ***Owner:Me*** and ***Group:oystein*** and ***Acesss files*** for Others.

The premissions tab of the install file itself shows ***Read and Write*** for ***Owner:Me*** and ***Group:oystein*** and ***Read-only*** for Others, and the allow executing file as program is checked.

How do I change the premission(s) so that I can run the install file?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: some typos

Comment: I feel abit silly, but doing sudo chmod -R 777 /home/oystein/matlab_r2017a_linux worked. Apologies for asking a potentially useless question, if a mod sees this feel free to delete it, hopefully someone else can benefit from this.

Comment: Perhaps `775` would have been okay?

Comment: @George Thanks for the tip, I'll look into the chmod documentation to see what 775 does!

Comment: `775` ==> `user 'rwx': user's group 'rwx': others 'rx'`..